# How to do Dependency Injection with NHibernate 3.3?

Tags: nhibernate, dependency-injection

I am trying to do DI on NHibernate 3.3 entities using Interceptors.

My code is:

```
public override object Instantiate( string clazz, EntityMode entityMode, object id ) {
    if( entityMode == EntityMode.Poco ) {

        dynamic x = _mappings.RootClasses.FirstOrDefault( hc => hc.Name.StartsWith( clazz ) );
        if( x == null )
            x = _mappings.SubClasses.FirstOrDefault( sc => sc.Name.StartsWith( clazz ) );
        if( x == null )
            x = _mappings.UnionSubclasses.FirstOrDefault( usc => usc.Name.StartsWith( clazz ) );

            if( x != null ) {
            Type type = Type.GetType( x.Name );  //Assembly.GetAssembly( typeof( Person ) ).GetTypes().FirstOrDefault( x => x.FullName == clazz );
            if( type != null ) {
                if( _kernel.HasComponent( type ) ) {
                    object instance = _kernel.Resolve( type );
                    _session
                        .SessionFactory
                        .GetClassMetadata( clazz )
                        .SetIdentifier( instance, id, entityMode );
                    return instance;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return base.Instantiate( clazz, entityMode, id );
}
```

The instance being returned is fine: I can check inside the watch window that the Id is properly set.

But, as soon as I do not peek into the object, but leave it alone, I get the following exception:
**Provided id of the wrong type. Expected: System.Int32, got UtenteProxy**

I get the same exception with the following call: _session.CreateCriteria().List();

Any hints as to what I should be looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Well, after a night sleep, I found the solution: the classes that will be instantiated by the interceptor need to be declared Lazy=false.

This way NHibernate is not expecting a proxy, and everything works fine.